# Is there a performance impact by turning on LARGEADDRESSAWARE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am keen to know how the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` switch works and cannot find much about the implementation details.

Can anybody describe what is happening when the switch is used and its consequences (aside from allowing a process to access more memory)?

Comment: The performance impact is in the /3GB switch. If you turn on /3GB and don't set /LARGEADDRESSAWARE then you're paying for something you're not using.

Comment: @RaymondChen That does not make any sense to me. You imply that using `/3GB` switch is costly. Does that mean that `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is costly as well, or that it is free, if `/3GB` is on?

Comment: @theswine `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is free if `/3GB` is already on. The `/3GB` makes the memory manager do extra work to keep an extra 1GB free. The `/LARGEADDERSSAWARE` says "Give me access to that extra 1GB which you worked so hard to create."

Comment: @RaymondChen right. But why is it slower in x64 then? In there, /3GB (and much more) should be by default, no?

Comment: @theswine It is not slower in x64. The kernel may has less virtual memory available under the /3GB flag on x86 systems. That may impact its performance, because it might have to page some things out. And the kernel might have less memory available for its file cache. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232(v=vs.85).aspx for an explanation of /3GB.

Comment: @Christopher I would say it is definitely slower, see my answer. Not by much, but it is. It might very well be an OS thing, not necessarily related to the code. If you are up to it, you can try running a different benchmark, it would be interesting to have the results confirmed or disproved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run a simple benchmark using the [SLAM++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slam-plus-plus/) library on *[Venice](http://services.eng.uts.edu.au/~sdhuang/Venice2.png)*, *[Sphere](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/slam-plus-plus/screenshots/sphere25_solution.png)* and *100k* datasets:

```xml
Dataset |  Time x86 | Time x86 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE |   Time x64
 Venice | bad_alloc |                 4276.524971 | 300.315826 sec
 Sphere |  2.946498 |                    3.605073 |   1.727466 sec
   100k | 46.402400 |                   50.196711 |  32.774384 sec
```

All times are in seconds. There you have it - the performance toll can be **substantial**. This is mostly doing BLAS operations, sometimes accelerated using SSE, and the whole thing is quite memory bound. Note that the peak memory usage on *Venice* in x86 was slightly over 3.5 GB (I believe it can be up to 4 GB in an x64 system), in x64 it was a bit under 4.3 GB. The other datasets use much less memory, well below 2 GB.

In case of x86 `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` on *Venice*, t seemed that the OS wants to keep most of the >2 GB in the paging file, although the memory usage jumped to >3 GB when the data was accessed - so the extra cost may stem from aggressive paging. Also, there is some advantage to arithmetic operations in x64 over x86 (the program can use extra registers, etc.), which is probably why ordinary x86 is slower than x64 on the small datasets.

This was measured on a machine with 2x [AMD Opteron 2356 SE](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Third%20Generation%20Opteron%202356%20-%20OS2356WAL4BGH%20(OS2356WAL4BGHWOF).html) and 16 GB of 667 MHz DDR2, running Windows Server 2003 x64.

On Windows 7, [Intel Core i7-2620M](http://ark.intel.com/products/52231/Intel-Core-i7-2620M-Processor-(4M-Cache-2_70-GHz)), 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 machine:

```xml
Dataset |  Time x86 | Time x86 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE |   Time x64
 Venice | bad_alloc |                  203.139716 | 115.641463 sec
 Sphere |  1.714962 |                    1.814261 |   0.870865 sec
   100k | 18.040907 |                   18.091992 |  13.660002 sec
```

This has quite a similar behavior, x64 is faster than x86, and `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is slower (although not so much slower as in the previous case - it likely depends on a CPU or on an OS).

Answer (score 2):

Historically, 32-bit Windows systems would have a virtual memory layout where only the low 2 GB of process' address space would be used by the application; the upper 2 GB would be reserved for the kernel. This was the documented behavior. Changing the documented behavior is not cool, unless it's explicitly opt-in. That's what `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is for. It triggers a flag in the executable header that tells the system that the program won't mind using addresses above the 2GB boundary. With that flag, the system can allocate addresses from the low 3 GB and the upper 1 GB is for kernel.

How would you have to code the app so that this was a breaking change is a whole another question. Maybe some people would cast addresses to signed ints and compare them; that'd break if the addresses had bit 31 set.

EDIT: there's no performance impact from the switch per se. However, if the application routinely encounters memory loads over 2 GB, you can get some performance from caching more aggressively. Without the 3GB switch, an app can't consume over 2GB of virtual memory; with the switch, up to three.

Comment: This does not answer the question IMO, you are saying that stuff can break (maybe), but nothing about performance.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of applications that used the highest bit of a pointer to store a piece of information. Dirty hacks, but MS always tried very hard not to break compatibility :) My favourite was the original SimCity, which allocated memory - and immediately released it. Not much of a problem in DOS, but it failed horribly in Windows. So Windows had a piece of code that checked whether you're running SimCity, and if so, it ignored the memory release. People hack a lot more than necessary, but that's just the reality :))

Answer (score 0):

`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` does not have a performance impact, because it does not affect code generation.

Programs that do not set this flag only get virtual memory addresses < 2^31. Programs with this flag set may get virtual addresses > 2^31.

This is significant, because there may be subtle bugs in programs where they rely on signed integer math.

E.g. pointer casting to int:

```
void* p0 = ...; // from somewhere
void* p1 = ...; // from somewhere else

assert( p1 > p0 );
int diff = (int)p1 - (int)p0;
```

This will break in the presence of addresses > 2 GB.
So to be conservative, the OS does treat programs that do not have this flag set, as it 'may do something bad when encountering addresses > 2 GB'.

On the other hand on x86 systems, setting the `/3GB` flag reduces the amount of virtual memory the kernel has available, which might impact its performance.